# How to measure performance of K-Means cluster in R? [image & code included]

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am currently doing a K-means cluster analysis for some customer data at my company. I want to measure the performance of this cluster, I just don't know the library packages used to measure performance of it and I am also unsure if my clusters are grouped too close together.

The data feeding my cluster is a simple RFM (recency, frequency, & monetary value). I also included average order value per transaction by customer. I used the elbow method to determine the optimal number clusters to use. Data consists of 1400 customers and 4 metric values.

**Attached is also an image of the cluster plot & R Code**

**[image: Here is my clustering code:]**

```
drop = c('CUST_Business_NM')

#Cleaning & Scaling the Data
new_cluster_data = na.omit(data)
new_cluster_data = data[, !(names(data)%in%drop)]
new_cluster_data = scale(new_cluster_data)
glimpse(new_cluster_data)

#Elbow Method for Optimal Clusters
k.max <- 15
data <- new_cluster_data
wss <- sapply(1:k.max, 
              function(k){kmeans(data, k, nstart=50,iter.max = 15 )$tot.withinss})
#Plot out the Elbow
wss
plot(1:k.max, wss,
     type="b", pch = 19, frame = FALSE, 
     xlab="Number of clusters K",
     ylab="Total within-clusters sum of squares")

#Create the Cluster
kmeans_test = kmeans(new_cluster_data, centers = 8, nstart = 1000)
View(kmeans_test$cluster)

#Visualize the Cluster
fviz_cluster(kmeans_test, data = new_cluster_data,  show.clust.cent = TRUE, geom = c("point", "text"))
```

Comment: You have guys that are very close together on the PCA plot because there are some variables that are hugely different between 43,41,147 and the rest of your data. So this project can be very misleading. Do you know what is driving this separation on your first PCA?

Comment: If it is some outlier variables that is driving this on these observations, think about whether it makes sense to remove them, or transform it in some way, for example taking the log etc

Comment: @stupidwolf yes, these are  outliers. Huge one time customers who made a massive order.

Comment: ok yeah.. sorry not very familiar with your field, but I guess you can cap at it at some value? I think the clustering might be ok. And note, the answer below, it proposes withinss, between ss etc, these are very sensitive to outliers.

Comment: What i mean is this, most of the variance is going to be driven by these outliers, as long as I put these massive order guys into one or two group, viola, >50% variance most likely explained..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably do not want to measure the performance of `cluster` but the performance of the `cluster algorithm`, in this case `kmeans`.

First, you need to be clear what `cluster distance measure` you want to use. The result of the cluster computation is a `dissimilarity matrix`, thus the choice of the distance measure is critical, you can play with `euclidean`, `manhattan`, any kind of `correlation` or other distance measure, e.g., like this:

```
library("factoextra")
dis_pearson <- get_dist(yourdataset, method = "pearson")
dis_pearson
fviz_dist(dis_pearson)
```

This will give you the distance matrix and visualize it.

The output of `kmeans` has several bits of information. The most important with regard to your question are:

- `totss:` the total sum of squares
- `withinss:` vector of within-cluster sum of squares
- `tot.withinss:` total within-cluster sum of squares
- `betweenss:` the between-cluster sum of squares

Thus, **the goal is to optimize these** by playing with distances and other methods to cluster the data. Using `cluster` package, you can simply extract these measures by `mycluster <- kmeans(yourdataframe, centers = 2)` and then calling `mycluster`.

Side comment: `kmeans` requires the number of clusters defined by the user (additional effort) and it is very sensitive to outliers.

Comment: Thank you so much. How do I interpret the dis_pearson plot ?

Comment: Well, the basic idea is to get a feeling about dissimilarities across the variables. You could play with colours smth. like `fviz_dist(yourdistance, gradient = list(low = "#00AFBB", mid = "white", high = "#FC4E07"))`. This will illustrate which rows (of your data set) have large dissimilarities (red colour) and which appear to be similar (teal colour).